# During autoration, does it help to pump the cyclic to increase the RPM?

Tags: aerodynamics, rotorcraft

I have heard of the idea of moving the cyclic forward and backwards in order to get an increase in rotor RPMs. Does anyone have any information on this as to when you would use it or airspeeds it would only be effective at?

#### Scenario is low altitude autorotation/unpowered flight:

> About a 100 - 150 feet AGL, super slow (say 10 - 20 kts)
>   You lose an engine there.
>   The ideal thing would be to get as much airspeed as
>   possible to reduce that sink rate as compared to a vertical descent /
>   pull collective / do a hard run on.
>
> However presuming you had to come straight down (trees, power lines or
>   whatever) I have heard from more than one source that pushing the
>   cyclic back and forth at quick segments will help build RPM's but I
>   just couldn't figure out how.

Comment: I can see you having a momentary change until the governor kicks in and corrects the rotor RPM, but you shouldn't deviate too much.

Comment: In an autorotation

Comment: Wes, do you perhaps mean pushing forward on the cyclic to pitch down for more airspeed, and—once a little airspeed has built up—pulling back to convert that airspeed to rotor RPM? That sounds plausible, but not something I know much about (@Simon, care to chime in?). What I just described sounds like a slower maneuver than what you seem to have described, Wes.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, well the scenario is about a 100 to a 150 feet agl and super slow say ten to twenty kts. You lose an engine there the ideal thing would be to get as much airspeed as possible to reduce that sink rate as compared to a vertical descent pull collective and do a hard run on. However presuming you had to come straight down trees, power lines or what ever I have heard from more than one source that pushing the cyclic back and forth at quick segments will help build RPM's but I just couldn't figure out how

Comment: Are you unhappy with [the answer you got here](http://www.pprune.org/rotorheads/594151-pumping-cyclic-rotor-rpm-s.html#post9757680)?

Comment: What sources?  I cannot think of any advantage to doing this since  every control input takes energy out of the system through losses.  I can imagine an initial flare to preserve or re-gain RRPM followed by stick forward to gain airspeed all the way down to the final flare but backwards and forwards is not going to  help.

Comment: BTW, that slow at that height is likely not survivable.  You will have around 8 seconds, perhaps about 5 at 100 feet before you are on the ground.  To gain airspeed for the flare will need nose down all the way.

Comment: @Simon In a lot of helicopters that will bring a loss of Nr with initial Fwd Cyclic, and if it has a teetering head will likely unload the head with the risk of mast bumping, and possibly a blade going divergent and hitting your tail pylon. (Some Robinsons are vulnerable to that...depending on a number of factors and the situation).

Comment: What Simon says

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I wasn't thinking about stick forward enough to unload the disk!  Just to gain airspeed but I can think of no advantage to "pumping" the cyclic and stick forward for airspeed at the height the OP is asking about would be a one off adjustment.  You would only have enough time to gain speed down to 50 feet for maybe 2 or 3 seconds before the flare.

Comment: @Simon I hear ya, I was just trying to picture in my head the situation was not sure of the magnitude of control deflections being considered.  Your point on where in the H-V diagram the situation presents itself is spot on. (I think I address it in my answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cyclic *pumping* will likely degrade your performance

[As explained her](http://www.pprune.org/rotorheads/594151-pumping-cyclic-rotor-rpm-s.html#post9758268)e, it leads to rotor inefficiencies

> As far as moving the cyclic around goes it destroys lift as the TRT
>   vector is all over the place and not acting in one place or close too
>   it and more power is required

What is this TRT he's talking about?  [Total Rotor Thrust](http://helicopterforum.verticalreference.com/uploads/post-4966-1172830748.gif)

> In a still air hover, TRT is, in broad terms, equal and opposite to
>   weight. As the disc is tilted to commence a transition into forward
>   flight, the TRT vector is tilted and must be increased so that its
>   vertical component remains equal to weight if level flight is to be
>   maintained.

With [the above](http://www.pprune.org/rotorheads/403305-total-rotor-thrust-question.html#post5468590) in mind, pumping the cyclic with the engines working simply means that you need more power from your engine to keep your Nr up to fly, as you are being inefficient.

If you have no power, *pumping the cyclic* is counter productive to your efforts at maintaining Nr since the back and forth creates sequential inefficiencies, and more drag but you have no engine to restore Nr... and in the situation you describe, your precious Nr is a critical resource to your walking away from the forced landing or crash.

Depending on what is happening, a slight turn or flare (aft cyclic, not foreward) may load the head and preserve Nr a bit so that it's still turning with enough inertia to help you as you near the ground and need that cushion from the collective as you hit the ground.  Each bit of Nr you retain for that last pull is critical, in that situation.

It's a tough one, the low speed, not-quite-inside-the-Hv-diagram scenario that you presented.

Consult the manual for your model helicopter, and the H-V diagram.  Know your limitations.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback! You explained it very well to me! Thanks

Comment: @Wes glad to be of help.